# Sharepoint 2013 application design - list 11500 items per month

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

We have a requirement which is a kind of request and approval application which is for different set of countries. Total number of requests for all the countries sum up to 1500. So for approval history and all i would expect 1500* 7 ~11500 per month records in history list. I have some questions

1. Is it a good idea to prefer SharePoint or SQL?
2. In SharePoint is it better to store all the requests in one list differentiated by country codes or separate lists for each country?
3. I guess in SharePoint I should be thinking of an option to archive as well. So if I am archiving how should I be showing it in search results assuming that I implement C# code to bring and show the results in custom grid?

Insights on the above and any suggests will be helpful or share experiences if you have implemented any architecture of this sort.

Comment: Why * 7 ? Is this the case that you have 7 approval steps and create a history entry on each ?

Comment: Yes 3 to 5 approvals and in middle approver can send for more information to be entered for the user so that also should be logged in history

Answer (score 1):

1) I think SharePoint list can do it. Assuming you would need SharePoint for approvals themselves, there is no reason to break it into two platforms.

2) I would put them all in the same list. In any case you will pass 5000 item limit very quickly, so no real benefit in splitting them.

3) I sometimes use an add-on called DFFS (Dynamic Forms For Sharepoint). It has a nice vLookup capability. So when you go into the request, in a separate tab you can display all the history items in a nice format. Might or might not be useful in your specific case.

In any case, remember to index lookup column in History list pointing back to requests. Otherwise you won't be able to filter them after 5000 items.

Comment: For the second point if we have multiple lists it might not touch 5000 limit in a year. This 1500 requests are for approx 6 countries. So if we split it will be slightly under control though it cannot be guranteed but searching will be a major challenge here if we are using multiple list for countires. So according to your suggestion one list with all data and archive every year to different library?? Probably i should be looking at separate content db for this site collection should be planned inorder to segregate the load.